Using UserCreationForm
I am learning Django. I would like to understand below code.
class RegisterPage(FormView):
    template_name = 'base/register.html'
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    success_url = reverse_lazy('tasks')

    def form_valid( self, form ):
        user = form.save()
        if user is not None:
            login( self.request, user )
        return super( RegisterPage, self ).form_valid( form )
    
    def get( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('tasks')
        return super(RegisterPage, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

Can I use  def register( self, form ): instead of  def form_valid( self, form ):?
How self and form are passing here?
Can I use  def save( self, *args, **kwargs ): instead of  def get( self, *args, **kwargs ):?

Instead of asking "Can I use X instead of Y?" why don't you simply ask us about the thing you want to do? Those methods are named according to what a generic view in Django expects. Do you really just want to customize those names or is there something else that you want to do?

Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat. Actually I am learning django. I would like to know more about those.

I would recommend reading the documentation here when using FormView you are inheriting methods from other parent classes. The form_valid method is from the django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin parent class which has predefined arguments. Therefore you wouldn't use def register( self, form )  as the method doesn't exist in the parent classes. The same applies for changing the get method to save.
